# Mapping count of unique IDs per project

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am receiving an Array of Objects like so

```
[
    {
       "payload":{
          "correlation":{
             "metadata":{
                "customerId":"12345",
                "project":"Project One"
             }
          }
       }
    },
    {
       "payload":{
          "correlation":{
             "metadata":{
                "customerId":"12345",
                "project":"Project Two"
             }
          }
       }
    },
    {
       "payload":{
          "correlation":{
             "metadata":{
                "customerId":"12345",
                "project":"Project Two"
             }
          }
       }
    },
    {
       "payload":{
          "correlation":{
             "metadata":{
                "customerId":"54323",
                "project":"Project One"
             }
          }
       }
    }
]
```

What I am trying to do is count all the unique customerId's per project.  So for the above data, I would expect

```
Project One: 2
Project Two: 1 //because 12345 is shown twice for Project Two, we only want unique so count it as 1
```

So I can do the counts using a map, something like this

```
const lutProjects = new Map();
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  const project = value?.payload?.correlation?.metadata?.project;
  const custId = value?.payload?.correlation?.metadata?.customerId;
  
  lutProjects.set(project, (lutProjects.get(project) || 0) + 1);
});
```

However, this does not handle unique ids for each project, so outputs 2 and 2.

How can I also handle unique id's per project?

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kadetcj/)

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to add a separate key as projectID in your array which will carry a unique id and then you can count it out easily

Comment: You need to keep track of the customerIds by saving them in something like a dictionary having the project name as key and the list of unique customerids as value.

Comment: Oh, so if the same project has different customerId then it will be counted as a 2 for the project. Ok got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create an object with the `project` as key, and the value as an array containing the `customerId`, we can use `includes()` to check if this `customerId` is already known, and only add it to the array if not.

Then, we can use a second [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to change the array ow `customerId`'s to the `length` of the array:

```js
const data = [{"payload":{"correlation":{"metadata":{"customerId":"12345", "project":"Project One"} } } }, {"payload":{"correlation":{"metadata":{"customerId":"12345", "project":"Project Two"} } } }, {"payload":{"correlation":{"metadata":{"customerId":"12345", "project":"Project Two"} } } }, {"payload":{"correlation":{"metadata":{"customerId":"54323", "project":"Project One"} } } } ];

let res = data.reduce((prev, cur) => {
    const { customerId, project } = cur.payload.correlation.metadata;
    if (!prev[project]) prev[project] = [];
    if (!prev[project].includes(customerId)) {
      prev[project].push(customerId);
    }
    return prev;
}, {});
res = Object.keys(res).reduce((prev, cur) => ({ ...prev, [cur]: res[cur].length }), {});

console.log(res);
```

```json
{
  "Project One": 2,
  "Project Two": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try quick fix with below snippet

```js
let data = [{"payload":{"correlation":{"metadata":{"customerId":"12345","project":"Project One"}}}},{"payload":{"correlation":{"metadata":{"customerId":"12345","project":"Project Two"}}}},{"payload":{"correlation":{"metadata":{"customerId":"12345","project":"Project Two"}}}},{"payload":{"correlation":{"metadata":{"customerId":"54323","project":"Project One"}}}}]

data = Array.from(new Set(data.map(f => f.payload.correlation.metadata.project))).map(d => {
   return {
      [d]: [...new Set(data.filter(f => f.payload.correlation.metadata.project === d).map(c => c.payload.correlation.metadata.customerId))].length
   }
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in combination with an array of unique ids for each project, then use length on those array to know the final count.
Here is my proposition:

```
const arr = [
    {
       "payload":{
          "correlation":{
             "metadata":{
                "customerId":"12345",
                "project":"Project One"
             } 
          }
       }
    },
    {
       "payload":{
          "correlation":{
             "metadata":{
                "customerId":"12345",
                "project":"Project Two"
             }
          }
       }
    },
    {
       "payload":{
          "correlation":{
             "metadata":{
                "customerId":"12345",
                "project":"Project Two"
             }
          }
       }
    },
    {
       "payload":{
          "correlation":{
             "metadata":{
                "customerId":"54323",
                "project":"Project One"
             }
          }
       }
    }
]

const cb = (accumulator, { payload }) => {
    const { project, customerId } = payload.correlation.metadata
    if (!accumulator[project]) {
      return { ...accumulator, [project]: [customerId] }
    }
    else if (accumulator[project] && accumulator[project].indexOf(customerId) === -1) {
    return { ...accumulator, [project]: [...accumulator[project], customerId] }
    } else return accumulator
}

const initialAccumulator = {}

const result1 = arr.reduce(cb, initialAccumulator)
const result2 = Object.keys(result1).map(key => ({ [key]: result1[key].length }))
console.log(result2)
```